# Update ongoing notification with Flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-notification, awesome-notifications

Currently we are using the awesome notifications package to display a notification in our Flutter app. We want to constantly update the contents of this notification.
Specifically, we want to display a timer within the notification.
For now we create a new notification every second with the altered content. This means a lot of notifications are constantly created and removed.

Is there a way to update the existing notification instead of constantly creating a new one?

This with the package we are currently using or a different Flutter package. Ideally we would like to prevent having to use platform specific coding.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of `awesome_notifications` package, but I've tried `flutter_local_notifications` and it uses chronometer that can work as a timer for your notification. It places the timer at the summary area of the notification, not in the body, I suppose.

This is the code from the sample project:

```
Future<void> _showNotificationWithChronometer() async {
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      when: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - 120 * 1000,
      usesChronometer: true,
    );
    final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }
```

Also check out the [full example code here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example) and explore the rest of the possibilities.